# Is there a formula to find a permutation from a given rank?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, algorithms

Observing, for example, a set of permutations from 4 choose 2:

1. [1, 2]
2. [1, 3]
3. [1, 4]
4. [2, 3]
5. [2, 4]
6. [3, 4]

Does such a formula exist to go from a permutation's rank to the values of it's permutation (ex. 2 -> [1,3]) without first generating the possibilities algorithmically?

Comment: Yes.  It looks like you are doing combinations, not permutations, as you don't have the other orders of the pairs in your list.  See the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) for one way.

Comment: Ah, that looks to be what i was looking for; thank you!